# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'path')

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

My images arent displayed and Im getting error from the title. This is my code:

```html
<theme-card
  v-for="theme in themes"
  :router-link="`/theme/${theme.slug}`"
  :key="theme.id"
  :name="theme.name"
  :tags="theme.tags"
  :id="theme.id"
  :imgPath="theme.image.path"
></theme-card>
```

this is my get request

```js
async getThemes() {
  await axios.get('api')
             .then((response) => (this.themes = response.data.data))
},
```

then in mounted:

```js
async mounted() {
  await this.getThemes()
}
```

in Theme card I receive img path as prop

```html
<img :src="`${imgPath}`" alt="theme-img" height="80" />
```

everything works without an image, so my get request and v-for works, only theme.image.path doesnt work and i dont know why, im using vue and ionic

Comment: theme.image does not seem to be defined, for at least one of the elements.  could you `console.log(this.themes)` or `console.log(response.data.data)`?

Comment: @oshell i have an array of 17 objects and i found that some of them really doesnt have image, but how can i display images that have path? that api isnt mine so i cant change it

Comment: you could simply pass empty string, but this could display broken image. so normally you want to add additional check using `v-if`. I added an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `theme.image` is not defined for some cases. To still display the list, simply use:

```
<theme-card
    v-for="theme in themes"
    :router-link="`/theme/${theme.slug}`"
    :key="theme.id"
    :name="theme.name"
    :tags="theme.tags"
    :id="theme.id"
    :image="theme.image"
></theme-card>
```

and then `v-if` to conditionally display the image

```
<img v-if="image" :src="`${image.path}`" alt="theme-img" height="80" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To display just the images which has paths, you can try the below code

```
<theme-card
    v-for="theme in themes"
    :router-link="`/theme/${theme.slug}`"
    :key="theme.id"
    :name="theme.name"
    :tags="theme.tags"
    :id="theme.id"
    :imgPath="theme.image? theme.image.path : ''"
></theme-card>
```